# Connection refused using --unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external

Tags: polkadot-js, websocket

I'm trying to connect to my local node using the --unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external flags when running the node. I can connect to the node through a node.js script, but not from a browser because the connection keeps getting refused.

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try adding `--rpc-cors all`. If you are running in `--dev` mode the default is to allow all origins.

Comment: @Burak The `-rpc-cors all` worked, many thanks!

Comment: @Burak - make it an answer for upvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `--rpc-cors all`. If you are running in `--dev` mode the default is to allow all origins.

If you view the node executable help (i.e. `./target/release/node-template --help`) the output includes:

```
--rpc-cors <ORIGINS>
  Specify browser Origins allowed to access the HTTP & WS RPC servers.
            
  A comma-separated list of origins (protocol://domain or special `null` value). Value of
  `all` will disable origin validation. Default is to allow localhost and
  <https://polkadot.js.org> origins. When running in --dev mode the default 
  is to allow all origins.
```