# Can not access Substrate from LAN network

Tags: network

I am testing Kitties [example](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/). Substrate template code is on Machine 1, Nodejs template  code is on Machine 2. And I encounted this error(when start nodejs template):

`Error Connecting to Substrate Connection to websocket 'ws://192.168.1.108:9944/' failed.`

Is there anyway to Substrate code listen from LAN network?

Comment: Check [this one](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/connection-refused-using-unsafe-rpc-external-unsafe-ws-external). You can try running your node with `--unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-cors all`.

Comment: @ArturGontijo It works fine, post as answer mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your node like:

`./target/release/node-kitties --dev --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-cors all`