# error : Origin denied: http://localhost:3000 , when i switch to local Alice node by chrome

Tags: frontier-node-template

when i study  substrate-docs/v3/tutorials/03-permissioned-network
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/blob/main/v3/tutorials/03-permissioned-network/index.mdx

success : start Alice node

```
./target/release/node-template \
--chain=local \
--base-path /tmp/validator1 \
--alice \
--node-key=c12b6d18942f5ee8528c8e2baf4e147b5c5c18710926ea492d09cbd9f6c9f82a \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
```

[image]

but when i switch from polkadot to Local Node - 127.0.0.1:9944 by chrome
[image]

Alice node terminal generate an error : Origin denied: http://localhost:3000
[image]

so can't switch to local node forever !!
[image]

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2491/380

Comment: Try adding --rpc-cors all. If you are running in --dev mode the default is to allow all origins.

Comment: this could be related to ad blockers on your browser.